# windows 8 visual studio user controls

Tags: microsoft-metro

I'm getting started with windows 8 visual studio.

I would like to embed user controls inside user controls, like I used to do in vb.net. The designer allows me to do this, I can visually create user control uc1, and put some controls on it. Then, I make a new user control, uc2. While I am editing uc2, uc1 is available in the toolbox, and I have built the project so it should be up to date.

But if I put uc1 into uc2, the frame is visible, but the contents are not, either at design time or runtime.

Am I missing something or is this something you can't do in windows 8?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not sure what I was doing wrong but I tried it all again and it seems to be working now.